# How do you activate the "Scavenger Hunt: Cat School Gear Upgrade Diagrams - Part 1" quest?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I usually activate the witcher gear upgrade quests by buying maps for them from vendors, but I haven't been able to find anything that activates the quest for the **Enhanced Feline** gear, which would be called

> Scavenger Hunt: Cat School Gear Upgrade Diagrams - Part 1

I know I can look up the locations for the diagrams online, but I want to be able to locate the diagrams through the in-game quest, not by just googling every diagram.

**How do I activate this quest?** If there's a map for it, I haven't been able to find it. Does a specific vendor sell the map?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure, there actually aren't maps available for every single witcher gear quest. **However, finding one of the diagrams will activate the quest.**

So, you can either explore and hope to find one diagram or you google one of them, either option will activate the quest allowing you to find the others.
I deliberately won't post any information on the diagrams, as you stated you want to find it through the ingame quest.

Comment: Also, it's not just blind luck exploring random wilderness - first, the locations overlap with places that you'll encounter in normal questing, second, there is the usual setup that the diagram hiding places have a mark visible from outside (i.e. a cat face scrawled at the entrance of a cave) and witcher senses highlight the mark in red so you know you might want to search the place thoroughly for that chest.